# division an integer into k parts

Tags: java, algorithm, integer-division

I'm programming in java and I need to formulate an algorithm. The requirements of the algorithm are:

- We have 3 Integer variables `n`, `m`, `k`;
- We want to divide `n` into `k` parts so that the sum of the `k`-parts
  are equal to `n` and each part is an integer between `1` and `m`.
- We want all possible combinations with the allowed integers.

For example with input set:

```
n = 7; m = 3; k = 4
```

we have two different combinations that we can formulate:

```
7 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 1
```

and

```
7 = 3 + 2 + 1 + 1
```

thank you all.

Comment: This smells like an NP-hard problem. Hopefully someone can name the problem to make your search easier

Comment: You want the "divisions" themselves or only their count (how much divisions exist)?

Comment: I'm not sure this exactly belong with the java tag. The question here is more an algorithm problem than a java problem. The java implementation shouldn't be an issue once you have the algorithm

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg It's not NP hard. It's not even regular hard. :)

Comment: Seem more like a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: amit, we want both the divisions and the number of them, in my example, there were 2 divisions and they were (2,2,2,1) & (3,2,1,1)

Comment: @Sneftel Actually, if he wants to print all the possible outputs, I don't think it's even in NP.  This is similar to [Bars and Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), but in here - order  does not matter, and you have an upper bound (which can be handled using generating functions)

Comment: You can solve this with recursion.

Comment: @Rishav Kundu , please get me the code of it, im not an expert in programming, thanks.

Comment: @ali I will, let me write it myself :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is a backtraking algorithm approach (with recursion), You can decrease parameters and get partials solutions and then check if you have a right solution.

```
public class Problem {

    private static void algorithm(int n, int k, int m) {
        algorithmRecursive(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, n, k, m, 1);
    }

    private static void algorithmRecursive(List<Integer> partial, int n, int k, int m, int min) {
        if ( (k > 0) ) {
            // Optimization
            if ((n <= k * m) && (n >= k*min)){
                for (int i = min; i <= Math.min(m, n); i++) {
                    List<Integer> newPartial = new ArrayList<>(partial);
                    newPartial.add(i);
                    algorithmRecursive(newPartial, n - i, k - 1, m, i);
                }
            }
        } else if (n == 0) {
            // Right solution
            System.out.println(partial);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        algorithm(7,4,3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of "number of divisions" you can use [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dynamic_programming), that follows the recursive formula:

```
D(0,0,j) = 1
D(x,0,j) = 0     x > 0
D(x,i,j) = 0     x < 0 or j<0
D(x,i,j) = D(x-j,i-1,j) + D(x,i,j-1)
```

The answer denoted by `D(n,k,m)` is the number of such divisions.

Complexity is `O(n*k*m)`

Java code:

```
public static int numDivisions(int n, int m, int k) {
    int[][][] D = new int[n+1][k+1][m];
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
            D[x][0][j] = 0;
        }
        D[0][0][j] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) { 
        for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                D[x][i][j] = 0;
                if (j > 0) D[x][i][j] += D[x][i][j-1];
                if (x-j-1 >=0) D[x][i][j] += D[x-j-1][i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return D[n][k][m-1];
}
```

As a side note, this is similar to the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem - but here order does not matter, and in addition you have upper bound on the number of "stars" in cell.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done easily with recursion. First check if you can divide `n` at all, that is when `n<=m*k && n>=k`, if not, return empty array.

If it is divisible, successively choose `m'` from range `[1..m]` and choose that as first number, then get the rest recursively for parameters `n'=n-'m, m'=m', k'=k-1`, then return all the result.

Recursion would successfully stop only for `n=0` and `k=0`. Time complexity should be the same as the size of output.